# Posting changes from public to protected version in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-server, versioning

Me [**USER1**] and my colleague [**USER2**] , have created the following ArcGIS 10.3.1 versioning workflow : 
[image]

Then each one of us started editing on his  respective public version . He then **reconciled** with  **[GISOWNER.QAQC]**  , disconnected from  [**USER2.VERSION2**] and reconnected to it as **[GISOWNER]** in order to **post** the changes to [GISOWNER.QAQC] but it failed due to insufficient privileges . He then later reconnected to his version as **[USER2]** but it also failed for same reason .

My questions are :

1) is this scenario even applicable ?

2) if so , how can we post changes?

2) if no  , what are the changes need to be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only admin of database can edit in  protected level. I think Gisowner user is not admin of database.

Protected: Any user may view the version, but only the owner or the geodatabase administrator may edit datasets in the version or the version itself.

See [Creating versions and setting permissions](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/creating-versions-and-setting-permissions.htm).

You can use private level instead of protected